# No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working on spring boot in Kotlin. I tried to create a custom query by joining tables. Needed a custom Entity class so created one.

Application starts but when I hit the query I get below error :
*org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.example.entity.NewResult]]*

My Entity Class looks like

`data class NewResult( val sectionCode: String, val sectionDescription: String, )`

My repository class:
`interface NewRepository: JpaRepository<SomeClass, UUID> {

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = """
    select 
        f.section_code as sectionCode, 
        m.section_description as sectionDescription
        from table1 f
            join table2 m on m.code_id = f.id
""")
fun search(): List<NewResult>
```

}`

Please let me know if this is a bug in JPA

Comment: try `select new full.package.name.NewResult(f.section_code, m.section_description) from table1 f join join table2 m on m.code_id = f.id`

Comment: Thanks @grigouille , I switched to coroutineCrudRepository as we were on initial phase and were any targeting suspendible functions.